# duplicate symbol error: WebRTC and OpenSSL in iOS

Tags: openssl, webrtc, duplicate-symbol

When I use webrtc in ios, found the webrtc and openssl have conflict, lead to compile fail, appears to be the identifier repeat definition, excuse me, how to solve this problem, thanks!~

error:

```
 #3 0x00bc2a50 in OBJ_NAME_add ()
    #4  0x00bf833f in EVP_add_cipher ()
    #5  0x00bfbfa8 in OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers ()
    #6  0x00bfbf7d in OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf ()
```

and more:

```
duplicate symbol _EVP_PKEY_print_public in:
        /Users/hucheng/Desktop/HF/WebRTC/Lib/libWebRTC.a(boringssl.evp.o)
        /Users/hucheng/Desktop/HF/HuiFen/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/lib-ios/libcrypto.a(p_lib.o)
    duplicate symbol _EVP_PKEY_print_private in:
        /Users/hucheng/Desktop/HF/WebRTC/Lib/libWebRTC.a(boringssl.evp.o)
        /Users/hucheng/Desktop/HF/HuiFen/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/lib-ios/libcrypto.a(p_lib.o)
    duplicate symbol _EVP_PKEY_print_params in:
        /Users/hucheng/Desktop/HF/WebRTC/Lib/libWebRTC.a(boringssl.evp.o)
        /Users/hucheng/Desktop/HF/HuiFen/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/lib-ios/libcrypto.a(p_lib.o)
    duplicate symbol _EVP_PKEY_CTX_new in:
        /Users/hucheng/Desktop/HF/WebRTC/Lib/libWebRTC.a(boringssl.evp_ctx.o)
        /Users/hucheng/Desktop/HF/HuiFen/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/lib-ios/libcrypto.a(pmeth_lib.o)
    duplicate symbol _EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id in:
        /Users/hucheng/Desktop/HF/WebRTC/Lib/libWebRTC.a(boringssl.evp_ctx.o)
        /Users/hucheng/Desktop/HF/HuiFen/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/lib-ios/libcrypto.a(pmeth_lib.o)
    duplicate symbol _EVP_PKEY_asn1_find in:
        /Users/hucheng/Desktop/HF/WebRTC/Lib/libWebRTC.a(boringssl.evp.o)
        /Users/hucheng/Desktop/HF/HuiFen/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/lib-ios/libcrypto.a(ameth_lib.o)
    duplicate symbol _EVP_PKEY_asn1_find_str in:
        /Users/hucheng/Desktop/HF/WebRTC/Lib/libWebRTC.a(boringssl.evp.o)
        /Users/hucheng/Desktop/HF/HuiFen/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/lib-ios/libcrypto.a(ameth_lib.o)
    duplicate symbol _d2i_PKCS12 in:
        /Users/hucheng/Desktop/HF/WebRTC/Lib/libWebRTC.a(boringssl.pkcs8.o)
        /Users/hucheng/Desktop/HF/HuiFen/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/lib-ios/libcrypto.a(p12_asn.o)
    duplicate symbol _PKCS12_free in:
        /Users/hucheng/Desktop/HF/WebRTC/Lib/libWebRTC.a(boringssl.pkcs8.o)
        /Users/hucheng/Desktop/HF/HuiFen/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/lib-ios/libcrypto.a(p12_asn.o)
    duplicate symbol _PKCS12_PBE_add in:
        /Users/hucheng/Desktop/HF/WebRTC/Lib/libWebRTC.a(boringssl.pkcs8.o)
        /Users/hucheng/Desktop/HF/HuiFen/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/lib-ios/libcrypto.a(p12_crpt.o)
    duplicate symbol _d2i_PKCS12_bio in:
        /Users/hucheng/Desktop/HF/WebRTC/Lib/libWebRTC.a(boringssl.pkcs8.o)
        /Users/hucheng/Desktop/HF/HuiFen/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/lib-ios
```

......

Comment: I have the same problem, did you resolve it?